# Can I commit and push in Java from within the code?

Tags: java, git, push, commit

I have a program that automatically updates files for my website and periodically uploads them as well. In the past, I uploaded the files through FTP which was pretty simple and worked *okay*.

I have since moved to GitHub Pages, and where syncing the website through the GitHub program manually is fairly simple, I have no idea how to automate this within my own program.

Is it possible to update my website from within code, and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this library (called JGit):

http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/